# ZIP contents as a Gray stream?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm writing a CL library to read MS Excel(tm) spreadsheets called "xlmanip" (not ready for prime time yet -- only reads "xlsx" spreadsheets, works for the 80% use case of "I want to operate on cell contents"... but I digress.)

One thing that worries me when reading "xlsx" (ZIP archives in XML format) is that the current ZIP handling library, Common Lisp ZIP, unpacks the compressed contents as a `(vector (unsigned-byte 8))`. For a large spreadsheet, that'll cause an issue for the end user.

One alternative I've thought about is delayed loading -- let-over-lambda a closure that effectively demand-loads the worksheet when needed. However, that's just delaying the inevitable.

Are there any ZIP file CL libraries out there that return a Gray stream to a ZIP component's contents as opposed to a (potentially large) `(vector (unsigned-byte 8))`?

**Edit: Clarification**

I'm looking for a ZIP component function that **returns a stream**, not one that *takes a stream*. The functions that take a stream write the ZIP component's contents directly to the file associated with the stream. I'd rather that *xlmanip* reads from a stream directly as if the ZIP component were (implicitly, virtually) a file.

Comment: Irrelevant comment, but someone is going to ask: `xlmanip`'s code is on gitlab.

Answer (score 1):

[Chipz](http://method-combination.net/lisp/chipz/) can decompress a ZIP to a stream. It provides a decompress functions where you give it an output stream and a input stream to decompress and it returns the output stream where the decompressed contents can be read.

Comment: From reading the code, it writes directly to a stream, but doesn't look like it creates a stream that can be read. It also doesn't fit the requirement: ZIP is an archive format with a table of contents, not a gzip file.

Comment: @ScottM: I think that `chipz:make-decompressing-stream` can do what you want when given the `zip::zipfile-entry-stream` as input stream.

Comment: @Svante: `zip::zipfile-entry-stream` is not exported. (My bad... it is, part of the `zipfile` structure.) I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Svante: Nope. `zipfile-entry-stream` is not exported. The `zipfile` structure is not exported... it's supposed to be opaque for some unknown reason. But it was a good idea.

Comment: @Svante: Even if I tell SBCL or CCL to use the internal `zipfile-entry-stream` name, there's an issue with Chipz's `deflate`.